# kernel of a linear functional and a subspace of codimension. one

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a problem in understanding the proof a theorem/ lemma involving the subspace of codimension one and the kernel of a non-zero linear functional. I understand the first part of the proof but couldn't decipher the second part. Although it says "clearly", it is not for me. The statement and proof are as follows.

> The kernel of a non-zero linear functional $f$ on a linear $X$ is a subspace of codimension one and a linear subspace $Z$ of codimension one is the kernel of a non-zero linear functional on $X$.
>   *Proof.*
>   For $x_0\in X\backslash ker(f)$, $f(x)\neq 0$ and for any $x\in X$,
>   $$x=\frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)}x_0+y,\;\mathrm{where}\; y\in \ker(f).$$
>   This shows that $\ker(f)$ is a subspace of codimension one.
>   For $x_0\in X\backslash Z$, and $x\in X$ can be represented uniquely in the form $x=\lambda x_0+y$, where  $\lambda$ is a scalar and $y\in Z$.
>   Define a function $f$ on $X$ by $f(x)=\lambda$.
>   Then, clearly, $f$ is linear and $\ker(f)=Z$.

Here is my attempt to understand the second part:

For $x_0\in X\backslash Z$, and $x\in X$ can be represented uniquely in the form $x=\lambda x_0+y$, where  $\lambda$ is a scalar and $y\in Z$.

Let $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be two scalars and choose $y_1,y_2\in Z$ . Then, they have unique representation as:
 $$x_1= \lambda_1 x_0+y,\; x_2= \lambda_2 x_0+y.$$
Define a function $f$ on $X$ by $f(x)=\lambda$.
Now, $f(\alpha x_1+\beta x_2)=f((\alpha\lambda_1+\beta\lambda_2)x_0+\alpha y_1+\beta y_2)=f((\alpha \lambda_1+\beta \lambda_2)+y')$, where $y'=\alpha y_1+\beta y_2\in Z$ since $Z$ is a subspace.  Then, $f(\alpha x_1+\beta x_2)=\alpha \lambda_1+\beta \alpha_2=\alpha f(x_1)+\beta f(x_2)$, which shows that $f$ is linear.

*I have a problem proving that $Z=\ker(f)$. Any help appreciated.*

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of $f$, we have $\lambda x_0+z\in\ker f$ with $z\in Z$, iff $\lambda=0$.

*Spelling it out*:
If $z\in Z$, then $z=0x_0+z$ is its decomposition in $X=\Bbb Rx_0\oplus Z$, so we have $f(z)=0$ by definition of $f$. 
Conversely, if $f(x)=0$ and the decomposition of $x$ is $x=\lambda x_0+z$, then, again by definition of $f$, we have $\lambda=0$, thus $x=z\in Z$.

Comment: I think the $y$ in $x=\lambda x_0+y$ has to belong to $\ker(f)$ for $Z\subset \ker(f)$. We also have to prove the reverse inclusion. I have no idea how to do that, though.

Comment: See my edit. All we use is the uniqueness of the decomposition, and the definition of $f$.